# Counting true booleans in an objects property

Tags: javascript, boolean

Hi i need a function to count the "online:true" property of different object "usuarios", could anyone help???

````
    //     toni: {
    //         edad: 33,
    //         online: true
    //     },
    //     emi: {
    //         edad: 25,
    //         online: true
    //     },
    //     fran: {
    //         edad: 25,
    //         online: false
    //     },
    //     agus: {
    //         edad: 24,
    //         online: false
    //     }```
````

Comment: Can you share your attempts at solving it? And, please fix the code snippet in your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Collect all values using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) count all the `online:true`

```js
const obj = {
  toni: {
    edad: 33,
    online: true,
  },
  emi: {
    edad: 25,
    online: true,
  },
  fran: {
    edad: 25,
    online: false,
  },
  agus: {
    edad: 24,
    online: false,
  },
};

const result = Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr.online) ++acc;
  // or
  // if (curr.online === true) ++acc;
  return acc;
}, 0);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can also simplify with `Object.values(obj).reduce((count, user) => count + (user.online ? 1 : 0), 0)`. And since all the nested objects have the `online` key and are booleans, you can also write it as `Object.values(obj).reduce((count, user) => count + Number(user.online), 0)`.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan Thanks for the suggestion, But I've written it so that OP can understand it better, rather to make it concise and make it hard to understand

Comment: As you mentioned, it was a suggestion. Feel free to ignore :)